# How do I represent a list of strings and a list in Java?

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I have data of the form

```
ith entry = string1, string2....fixed number N of strings, 
            (name1, name2,....variable number of strings)
```

i.e. it is a list of (N strings and a list of variable size)

I currently have `List<List<String>>` and I'm thinking just treat the `N+1th` to the last string differently...but is there a better way to represent this data? Specifically I'd like to be able to interact with (name1, name2...) as a list rather than as strings

Comment: Could you be more abstract, and provide the goal of the problem ? Currently I do not know what is the issue and why you are using structure like that. Therefore I can not answer your question.

Comment: Is only the last element of the list (N+1th index as you call it) a list itself?

Comment: You are not very clear.. Can you explain a little bit more??

Comment: Perhaps make it a List<CustomFoo> where class CustomFoo{String fixedStrings[N];List<String> vStrings}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrapper like this may be used:

```
Class MyData
{
    private String[] fixedData;
    private List<String> variableData;
    public MyData(int fixedSizeN) {
         fixedData = new String[fixedSizeN];
         variableData = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    //public get/set go here
}

List<MyData> comboData;
```

Answer (score 1):

Think in Objects, if a fixed list of strings AND a variable list of strings represent something in your problem domain, wrap both in a class. In this way, you can increase your encapsulation.